# Looping Through Text Inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an app where I want the user to specify a number of text fields and then render this amount of fields dynamically. I'm having trouble setting up the state so that it is unique for each field. Here is the code segment:

```
        var fieldsArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; i <= this.props.numToShow; i ++){
        fieldsArray.push(
            <div>
                <label>
                    <div className="label">{i}</div> 
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.value} name={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
            </div>
            );
        }

    return (
      <div className = 'inputs'>
        {fieldsArray}
      </div>
    );
```

Currently, when I change one of the fields, all the other fields update with that unique fields state. Here is the handleChange function that sets the state:

```
    handleChange: function(e){
       this.setState({
           value: e.target.value,
       });
    }
```

Is it possible to initialize the state as an array and keep track of the inputs that way? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping an array of values in state would work fine. You'll just have to make sure you're passing the index of the input so you know what to update. `bind` helps with this:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
  }

  handleChange(i, e) {
    this.setState({
      values: { ...this.state.values, [i]: e.target.value }
    });
  }

  render() {
    var fieldsArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= this.props.numToShow; i++) {
      fieldsArray.push(
        <div>
            <label>
                <div className="label">{i}</div> 
                <input 
                  type='text' 
                  value={this.state.values[i]} 
                  name={this.state.values[i]} 
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
            </label>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className = 'inputs'>
        {fieldsArray}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The program fails on the line with the spread operator. I'm trying to further understand what this line is doing. The ...this.state.values persists all current state values and the [i]: e.target.value sets the value of the current input to the target value (shouldn't this be values[i] instead?)

Not sure if my stack doesn't support ... or not, but upon further research seems like that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the spread operator set up with Babel. The reason I'm using it is so that the array value is a new object, with just that index changed. You can try this instead: `var newValues = this.state.values.slice(); newValues[i] = e.target.value; this.setState({ values: newValues });`

Comment: Note that binding in render may cause performance issues https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-render

Comment: Thanks @jacob, for your help. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
                               onChange={(e) => {
                                    var newPresetList = [...presetList]

                                    newPresetList.map((_item) => {
                                      if (_item.id === item.id) {
                                        _item.preset_name = e.target.value
                                        return
                                      }
                                    })
                                    setPresetList(newPresetList)
                                  }}
```